# The space $X$ = (({$\frac{1}{n} | n \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ \ {$0$}) $\cup$ {$0$}) $\subset \mathbb{R}$, check homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem: The space $X$ = (({$\frac{1}{n} | n \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ \ {$0$})  $\cup$ {$0$}) $\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$  are not homeomorphic in their standard topologies (but $X$ is the continuous one-to-one image of $\mathbb{Z}$).**

I am not sure whether I am correct or wrong in this, but I did it in this way:

$X$ doesn't contain {$0$}, and its not open in $X$. Also, $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete, so let $h: X \to Z$ is a continuous one-to-one and onto mapping. Let, $h(0) = x$, since {$x$} is open, therefore, its inverse $h^{-1}${$x$} = {$0$} is also open in $X$. Hence, there doesn't exist any continuous one-to-one and onto map between $X$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Please help me give a better proof with proper explanation and arguments for this. Also, notation and style should be best. Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: $X$ contains {$0$}?

Comment: Hi! Your argument is correct. Perhaps in the first line of your proof is: "$X$ contains $\{0\}$..."

Answer (score 1):

They idea is OK, I'd write it like this:

Suppose that $h: X \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a homeomorphism. Then $\{h(0)\}$ is open (as all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ are) and by 1-1-ness and continuity, $\{0\} = h^{-1}[\{h(0)\}]$ is open in $X$, contradiction. In short, no injective continuous map into $\Bbb Z$ exists, even.

Dually, you can show no map $f: \mathbb{Z} \to X$ can be open and onto: let $x$ be such that $h(x)=0$ by onto-ness. But $\{0\}=f[\{x\}]$ would then be open, contradiction.

Comment: I didnt get few things which u said, ur including 2 contradictions in your proof. Is that possible or can we do that? Secondly, u said by 1-1ness and continuity, are you using the definition of a function to be continuous?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun the main observation is that $\{0\}$ is not open in $X$. Yes, I use that the inverse image of open is open.

Comment: where did u excatly use contradiction? and how r u contradicting in the 1st and 2nd parts?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun I show in both cases that the existence of the function leads to the conclusion that $\{0\}$ would be open in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are not homeomorphic.

Every subset of $\Bbb{Z}$ is clopen, but the subset $\{0\}$ of $X$, is not.